# Failed to install ASP.NET application onto new IIS server

Tags: c#, asp.net

So we have some scripts that utilize an API that is developed in-house by our parent company. Basically, we have utilized their API to create some ASP.NET code to retrieve check images, deposit images, statements, etc. through the customer's internet banking interface.

We recently started working with a brand new IIS on a new server.

The code in Checks.aspx.cs referring the code in UnityC.cs.

The first file is located at C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TestIB\Checks.aspx.cs.

The second file is located at C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TestIB\App_Code\UnityC.cs

Basically, the Checks.aspx.cs script parses out the GET call and feeds the variables into the UnityC.cs, where the check image is returned to the user in a browser. At this point, I keep getting the following error:

> "Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'InternetBankingUnity' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

The server is setup the same way as our other servers, so I am very confused. The line that throws the error in the Checks.aspx.cs script is as follows:

```
InternetBankingUnity.OBUnityC OB_Unity = new InternetBankingUnity.OBUnityC();
```

Here is a little bit of code from the top of the Checks.aspx.cs file. I have tried doing using InternetBankingUnity to no avail. If I include the using statement, the error is on that line instead of the line mentioned above.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Text;
using InternetBankingUnity;

public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
```

A little exerpt from the UnityC.cs file showing the using statements, namespace, and class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Hyland.Types;
using Hyland.Unity;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Drawing;

namespace InternetBankingUnity
{
    public class OBUnityC
    {
```

Here is the relevant line from the checks.aspx page that is called from the URL passed into a browser:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Checks.aspx.cs" Inherits="_default" %>
```

I am at a loss as to why these scripts would be working fine at one site and be giving me compilation errors at another. We did just copy the scripts over from our TestIB setup to their site's TestIB setup...is there something I am missing here?

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Comment: These are not "scripts".  They're source files that get compiled to dll's.

Comment: My apologies for getting term the terms confused. What I included in the above post is just little exerpts showing the using statements from the code. The UnityC.cs contains numerous methods to connect, disconnect, do retrievals, rendering etc from the software.

Comment: Regardless of if they're scripts or source files though, any idea what the issue could be? This is how it is set up in numerous other locations and is working just fine unless there's something obvious I am missing.

Comment: It could be that the class depends on something else.  I notice usings for something called Hyland.Types, etc..

Answer (score 0):

Apparently whatever dll the InternetBankingUtility namespace gets compiled into is not in your bin folder where the app. is running from. I guess just make sure it's there and is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Copying files over almost never works (flawlessly), especially if this is a web application (mention if it is web application or web site). Instead open the solution in Visual Studio, right click it and select **Publish**. Choose a publish method and follow the wizard. I highly recommend to install [Web Deploy](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy) on the server and go through this option from Visual Studio. If not, publish on the local file system and copy the folder contents over to the IIS server.

Comment: So I am not entirely sure if this is the case, but I copied the files onto the desktop instead of directly into the. Also scrapped the current IIS setup and re installed and configured it and now it is not having any trouble finding the name space.